# How to dynamically compute the radius for heatmap.js according to the data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heatmap, bandwidth

I'm using the leafleat and heatmap.js API (the new 2.x version). There is a trouble setting the radius value. I'm trying to perform some bandwidth selection methods of kernel density and get an unfavourable result. Is there any reasonable way to compute the radius according to the characteristics of spatial distribution for data?

The question is how to dynamically compute the appropriate radius or other parameters to generate the smooth heatmap even if distribution is badly sparse  ?

Here is my demo example:

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        var baseLayer = L.tileLayer(
                'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: 'Copyright &copy; 2015',
                    maxZoom: 22,
                    minZoom: 10
                }
        );
        var cfg = {
            "blur": .85,
            "maxOpacity": .75,
            "minOpacity": 0.02,
            // scales the radius based on map zoom
            "scaleRadius": true,
            // if set to false the heatmap uses the global maximum for colorization
            // if activated: uses the data maximum within the current map boundaries
            //   (there will always be a red spot with useLocalExtremas true)
            "useLocalExtrema": true,
            // which field name in your data represents the latitude - default "lat"
            latField: 'lat',
            // which field name in your data represents the longitude - default "lng"
            lngField: 'lng',
            // which field name in your data represents the data value - default "value"
            valueField: 'count'
            ,
            gradient: {
                0.0: "rgba(000,000,255,0)",
                0.1: "rgba(000,000,255,1)",
                0.2: "rgba(000,255,000,1)",
                0.5: "rgba(000,255,000,1)",
                0.8: "rgba(255,255,000,1)",
                1.0: "rgba(255,000,000,1)"
            }
        };
        /*  legend code */
        // we want to display the gradient, so we have to draw it
        var legendCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        legendCanvas.width = 100;
        legendCanvas.height = 10;
        var legendCtx = legendCanvas.getContext('2d');
        var gradientCfg = {};
        var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(cfg);
        var southWest = L.latLng(15.78, 73.5577),
                northEast = L.latLng(53.56086, 134.7739),
                bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
        var map = new L.Map('map_l', {
            center: new L.LatLng(36.105215, 120.384428),
            zoom: 11,
            maxBounds: bounds,
            layers: [baseLayer, heatmapLayer]
        });

        function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
            return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
        }

        // generate 1000 datapoints
        // randomly generate extremas
        var t = [];
        var iii;
        for (iii = 0; iii < 1000; iii++) {
            var xx = getRandomArbitrary(119.5, 120.5);
            var yy = getRandomArbitrary(36, 36.2);
            var cc = getRandomArbitrary(1, 1000);
            // btw, we can set a radius on a point basis
            var rr = getRandomArbitrary(0.001, 0.005);
            // add to dataset
            t.push({lng: xx, lat: yy, count: cc, radius: rr});
        }
        heatmapLayer.setData({min: 1, max: 1000, data: t});
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: I appended my code. Thanks for your kindly help